# How do I compare a string value in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I am pulling data from a SQL database, I am filling in missing data that is blank or missing with the following statement.

```
string.Join(
    ",",
    from
        r in siteData.Rows.OfType<DataRow>() 
    select
        r[28] == DBNull.Value ? "null" : r[28]);
```

I would like to replace a value of -9999 with a blank value as well.

Comment: check out MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 6):

In SQL, use `CASE WHEN`:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN someValue = -9999 THEN '' ELSE someValue END AS colName
```

In Linq, just change your ternary:

```
siteData.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select( r => r[28] == DBNull.Value || r[28] == -9999 ? "" : r[28] )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
string.Join(
    ",",
    from
        r in siteData.Rows.OfType<DataRow>() 
    select
        string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)r[28]) ? "null" : r[28]);
```